# Time, Date, and Half Pay?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a view named `vwPayroll` that returns a certain column. However, upon running the code, I keep getting this error message:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
> Operand type clash: time is incompatible with tinyint

One of the columns that I'm trying to create is called `OTRate` which is from a table called `Calculated`.

This column would determine the time and a half pay rate. I can probably figure out the time and date, but how do I squeeze in the half pay rate?

This is the code I managed to come up with:

```
SELECT 
    PerFrom, PerThru, PayID, PayPeriod.PPID, 
    FirstName + LastName AS EmpName,
    PayRate, CONVERT(Time, GETDATE()) AS OTRate, 
    WorkHours, HolHours, SickHours,
    VacHours, PersHours, OTHours, 
    BaseCost, SpouseCost, DepCost, DentalCost,
    Spouse, Dependants, WHAllowance, SpouseIns, DepIns, TaxRate
FROM                     
    dbo.Calculated 
CROSS JOIN
    dbo.Benefits 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.EmpData ON dbo.Benefits.BenPlanID = dbo.EmpData.BenPlanID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.PayPeriod 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Hours ON dbo.PayPeriod.PPID = dbo.Hours.PPID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.[Work] ON dbo.Hours.WorkID = dbo.[Work].WorkID 
      ON dbo.EmpData.EmpID = dbo.[Work].EmpID
WHERE 
    OTHours <= 32;
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: Please post sample data and expected results - ideally as a SQL FIddle.

Comment: FYI [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/). Instead, alias your objects in the `FROM` and use those to qualify your column names. Also, why is the `ON` for `PayPeriod` after the `ON` for `Work`? There's no need for it to be when all the `JOIN`s are `INNER JOIN`s.

Comment: As for the error, somewhere you are comparing a `time` with a `tinyint`; we don't have access to your instance so we don't know where that is.

Comment: I guess that error is probably coming from `OTHours <= 32`. `OTHours` is probably `TIME`. You can't compare a `TIME` with `INT`

Comment: The OTHours column is supposed to use a conditional function to determine the number of current WorkHours that qualify as overtime. If it's a holiday, then 32 hours should be the limit. If a TIME cannot be compared with an INT, then what's an alternative I could use?

Comment: @rylew0925 The time datatype has a domain with upper limit of "23:59:59" (roughly - depends on actual definition). So it can NEVER be anything close to "32 hours". You need to clarify your data and your goal for others to help you write a useful query.